# Does there exist terminology to discern NFA states and NFA-transformed-into-DFA state?

Tags: finite-automata, terminology

I can't find this from surface search in the literature

When one observes/simulates NFA after processing several characters, one has to consider both "internal states of NFA" (individual nodes) and "state of the whole NFA" - which nodes are active - that can be seen as state of DFA that that automata is equivalent to.

**Is there an already existing different terminology for at least one of these?** so that I can stop confusingly referring to both as "NFA state"/"state of NFA"

Answer (score 1):

For the first term we simply use the word "state".
For the second term, using "state of the NFA" is confusing because we read it as "one of the NFA's states". If you are not sure which terminology to follow, then you can state explicitly what you mean, or define a term clearly before using it.

So for an NFA $A = \langle \Sigma, Q, Q_0, \delta, F \rangle$, a subset $S\subseteq Q$ of states, and a finite word $u\in \Sigma^*$, you can:

- **Write it explicitly:** $T$ is the set of states that $A$ can reach upon reading $u$ from some state in $S$.
- **Extend $\delta$ to set of states and words, and then use it** (quoting from what we usually write in papers):

> we sometimes extend $\delta$ to sets of states and finite words.
> Then, $\delta: 2^Q\times \Sigma^* \to 2^Q$ is such that for every $S  
>  \in 2^Q$, finite word $u\in \Sigma^*$, and letter $\sigma\in \Sigma$,
> we have that $\delta(S, \epsilon) = S$, $\delta(S, \sigma) =   
> \bigcup\limits_{s\in S}\delta(s, \sigma)$, and $\delta(S, u \cdot \sigma) =  
>  \delta(\delta(S, u), \sigma)$. Thus, $\delta(S, u)$ is the set of states that $A$ may reach when it reads $u$ from some state in $S$.

and from this point, you can write $T = \delta(S, u)$. In fact, in the literature, the term $\delta(S, u)$ is usually used, and it is not hard to guess what it means. So the answer to your question is yes, the terminology exists.

Answer (score 0):

I will share a pedantic answer:

The first concept is called simply "state".

Strictly speaking, the second concept does not exist, and reflects a misunderstanding of NFAs.  NFAs are nondeterministic.  This means that, at each step of execution, the NFA chooses one state to transition to (not a set of states; one state).  The choice is nondeterministic, so you can think of it as magically making a "lucky choice" if any exists.

Now, we know that nondeterministic execution is equivalent to cloning many copies of the NFA, where each copy follows a different execution trace; and thanks to the [subset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction), this is in turn equivalent to some DFA where each state of the DFA corresponds to a set of states of the NFA.  That is where the set of states comes from.

Therefore, if you needed to discuss both concepts, one possibility would be to refer to a "NFA-state" or "state of the NFA", vs a "DFA-state" or "state of the DFA obtained by the subset construction".

Ultimately, you can use any terminology you want, so long as it is understandable by the reader.  You might want to explain your terms before first use.